# OnTouchListener irregular on Android 4.1.1 JellyBean

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am suffering a really weird problem with my OnTouchListener. I upgraded my Galaxy Nexus to 4.1.1 last night and the following code which is still working on all previous android OS version does not work at all. I guess there is some problem with the calling of this listener. Following is the code and please ignore the logic if you find it complex just see the placement of logs and the output: -

```
private OnTouchListener drag = new OnTouchListener() {
    private float error_x = 0;
    private float error_y = 0;
    private int c = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("branch", "onTouch called " + ++c);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.i("branch", "1");
            error_x = event.getX();
            error_y = event.getY();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Log.i("branch", "2");
            refreshTriangleColor(v);
            root_layout.removeView(v);
            root_layout.addView(v);
            Point position = getViewPosition(v);
            if (position != null) {
                Log.i("branch", "3");
                if (triangle_red
                        .pointLiesInTriangle(position.x, position.y)) {
                    Log.i("branch", "4");
                    int x = Math.round(event.getRawX());
                    int y = Math.round(event.getRawY());
                    if (triangle_red.pointLiesInTriangle(x, y)) {
                        Log.i("branch", "5");
                        setViewPosition(v,
                                Math.round(event.getRawX() - error_x),
                                Math.round(event.getRawY() - error_y));
                    } else {
                        Log.i("branch", "6");
                        long d = 0;
                        d = Math.round(android.util.FloatMath.sqrt((((position.x - event
                                .getRawX()) * (position.x - event.getRawX())) - ((position.y - event
                                .getRawY()) * (position.y - event.getRawY())))));
                        if (d >= Util.convertDip2Pixels(MAX_RESISTANCE,
                                MelodyTriangle_AppActivity.this)) {
                            Log.i("branch", "7");
                            setViewPosition(v,
                                    Math.round(event.getRawX() - error_x),
                                    Math.round(event.getRawY() - error_y));
                            vibrate();
                        } else {
                            Log.i("branch", "8");
                            Point nearest_point = triangle_red
                                    .getNearestPointOnLine(new Point(x, y));
                            if (nearest_point != null) {
                                Log.i("branch", "9");
                                setViewPosition(
                                        v,
                                        Math.round(nearest_point.x
                                                - error_x),
                                        Math.round(nearest_point.y
                                                - error_y));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("branch", "10");
                    setViewPosition(v,
                            Math.round(event.getRawX() - error_x),
                            Math.round(event.getRawY() - error_y));
                }
            }
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.i("branch", "11");
            Point position = getViewPosition(v);
            if (position != null) {
                Log.i("branch", "12");
                if (!triangle_red.pointLiesInTriangle(position.x,
                        position.y)) {
                    Log.i("branch", "13");
                    if (api.voices[0].isPlaying()) {
                        Log.i("branch", "14");
                        api.voices[0].stopPlaying();
                    }
                    animateToLayout(v, red_layout);
                } else {
                    Log.i("branch", "15");
                    playVoice(v, position.x, position.y);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

The above code gives the following output when I try to drag: -

```
07-18 16:28:53.897: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 1
07-18 16:28:53.897: I/branch(31176): 1
07-18 16:28:54.007: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 2
07-18 16:28:54.007: I/branch(31176): 2
07-18 16:28:54.007: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 3
07-18 16:28:54.007: I/branch(31176): 3
07-18 16:28:54.007: I/branch(31176): 10
07-18 16:28:56.077: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 4
07-18 16:28:56.077: I/branch(31176): 1
07-18 16:28:56.124: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 5
07-18 16:28:56.124: I/branch(31176): 2
07-18 16:28:56.124: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 6
07-18 16:28:56.124: I/branch(31176): 3
07-18 16:28:56.124: I/branch(31176): 10
07-18 16:29:00.764: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 7
07-18 16:29:00.764: I/branch(31176): 1
07-18 16:29:00.803: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 8
07-18 16:29:00.803: I/branch(31176): 2
07-18 16:29:00.803: I/branch(31176): onTouch called 9
07-18 16:29:00.803: I/branch(31176): 3
07-18 16:29:00.803: I/branch(31176): 10
```

The problems noticed are:-

1. touch is not being called regularly due to which the dragging is not smooth. You have to smudge the view to move it slightly from its position hence not moving along with the touch. Whereas, it is regular in the previous versions.
2. event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is only true when you touch and release the view. Whereas it is being called almost every time on previous version as the view moves along the touch and whenever you release this is true.

Any idea whats going on wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try event.getActionMasked()?

Comment: Well it's just a shot in the dark, but getAction() has other bits that indicate which pointer is doing the action. getActionMasked() removes those bits. Probably won't make a difference with your problem but you might as well try it.

Comment: oh I see you mean instead of getAction... Let me try and I will get back soon...

Comment: What do you mean by problem 2? getAction() == ACTION_UP should only be true if the view is released, when else do you expect it to be called?

Comment: yes you are right but consider this:-

Assume the drag is working correctly i.e. when you drag the view your finger is always touching the view and the condition will be true as soon as you release.

However, this is not the case on 4.1.1. When I try dragging the view my finger leaves the view behind while it is pressed and hence it this condition never goes true even as my finger has displace off it. But when when you just touch down and touch up this condition goes true. Do you get it?

Comment: To further elaborate if you see the log that i have mention that is the print of 3 seconds of dragging in which onTouch is only called 9 times whereas on previous android OS versions onTouch is called around  74 times...

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you finally find a solution?

Comment: not yet :(... It is running fine on all previous versions, so this is still marked as open and marked as known issues in my builds... argh